# What's wrong with my Google Apps Script code? I get no error while debugging

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm no developer, but I followed [this tutorial to make a PDF from data in a spreadsheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9uU_KwGgzQ).

Everything went well, until I had to change some columns on my sheet and decided to create a new project. I adapted the code, but wasn't able to make it run again. All I get is a time-out, any error on debugger.

Follow the code below. Disclaimer: I hid the Google Drive files and folders IDs for privacy reasons.

```
function createBulkPDFs() {
  
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("doc-id-");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder-id");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder-id");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet-id").getSheetByName("produtos");

  const data = currentSheet.getRange(4, 2, currentSheet.getLastRow()-3, 33).getValues();

  let errors = [];

  data.forEach(row => {
    try{
    createPDF(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12],row[13],row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27], row[28], row[29],row[30], row[31], row[32], row[0] + " " + row[1], docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder);

    errors.push([""]);
    } catch(err){
      errors.push(["Failed"]);
    }
  });

  currentSheet.getRange(4, 35, currentSheet.getLastRow()-2, 1).setValues(errors);

}

function createPDF(tipo, nome, po, referencia, pack, statuscom, calculadora, statusatmkt, auto, disponibilidade, unidade, descricao,resumo,faz, nfaz, atencao, input, output, segmentos, dores, beneficios, complementar, similar, kit, pagina, op, ip, oa, ia, fin, seg, ben, data, pdfName, docFile, tempFolder, pdfFolder) {

  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
    body.replaceText("[tipo]", tipo);
    body.replaceText("[nome]", nome);
    body.replaceText("[po]", po);
    body.replaceText("[referencia]", referencia);
    body.replaceText("[pack]", pack);
    body.replaceText("[statuscom]", statuscom);
    body.replaceText("[calculadora]", calculadora);
    body.replaceText("[statusatmkt]", statusatmkt);
    body.replaceText("[auto]", auto);
    body.replaceText("[disponibilidade]", disponibilidade);
    body.replaceText("[unidade]", unidade);
    body.replaceText("[descricao]", descricao);
    body.replaceText("[resumo]", resumo);
    body.replaceText("[faz]", faz);
    body.replaceText("[nfaz]", nfaz);
    body.replaceText("[atencao]", atencao);
    body.replaceText("[input]", input);
    body.replaceText("[output]", output);
    body.replaceText("[segmentos]", segmentos);
    body.replaceText("[dores]", dores);
    body.replaceText("[beneficios]", beneficios);
    body.replaceText("[complementar]", complementar);
    body.replaceText("[similar]", similar);
    body.replaceText("[kit]", kit);
    body.replaceText("[pagina]", pagina);
    body.replaceText("[op]", op);
    body.replaceText("[ip]", ip);
    body.replaceText("[oa]", oa);
    body.replaceText("[ia]", ia);
    body.replaceText("[fin]", fin);
    body.replaceText("[seg]", seg);
    body.replaceText("[ben]", ben);
    body.replaceText("[data]", data);

  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();

  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
}
```

Does anyone know how can I make his work?

I tried to debug it, checked semicolons, but Google App Script doesn't give any clue of what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hi and welcome. "decided to create a new project". I'm wondering **EXACTLY** what you mean (and what you did) when you say you "created a new project". Would you please elaborate on this? For example, was the previous project unbound, is the new project unbound? Is the new project bound to something (what??).

Comment: Hi, Tedinoz, thanks for the welcome and your answer. I started from scratch and clicked "Novo projeto" - Portuguese for New Project - in the Apps Script panel. Does this clarify it enough?

Comment: Things to check: "sheet name" `produtos`, "data range" `Logger.log("data range = "+currentSheet.getRange(4, 2, currentSheet.getLastRow()-3, 33).getA1Notation())`, "error range" `Logger.log("data range = "+currentSheet.getRange(4, 35, currentSheet.getLastRow()-2, 1).getA1Notation())`, "template merge fields" - typically the template uses 'curly braces:`{}` but your code uses square brackets `[]`

Comment: The braces/brackets were the problem! I've been checking all the details like variables, range, and indentation, but the issue was more straightforward. Thank you very much, Tedinoz.